# Coloring brackets in TikZ matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I would like to have different colors for the left brackets of matrices but `every left delimiter/.style={red}]` gives my just the option to color all brackets the same color:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every left delimiter/.style={red}]
\matrix (m1) [matrix of nodes, left delimiter=[] {1 & 2\\};
\matrix (m2) [below of=m1, matrix of nodes, left delimiter=[] {1 & 2\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to color each matrix separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matrix` is just a special `node`, and I like writing TikZ code with the most plain TikZ command `\path`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[every left delimiter/.style={red}] 
(0,0)  node[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[}] (m1) {1 & 2\\};
\path[every left delimiter/.style={blue}] 
(m1)+(1,-1) node[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=\{] (m2) {3 & 4\\};
\path[every left delimiter/.style={orange}] 
(m2)+(-.5,-1) node[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[] (m3) {5 & 6\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used some thing like this in the past:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,environ}

\NewEnviron{pmatrixcolor}[1][red]{%
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
  \mathinner{\begingroup\color{#1}\left(\color{currentcolor}%
    \begin{matrix}
     \BODY
    \end{matrix} \color{#1}\right)\endgroup}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\]

\[
    \begin{pmatrixcolor}
        1 &2 \\
    \end{pmatrixcolor}
\]
\end{document}
```

Might point you in the right direction.